# Uploading csv file from frontend giving error

Tags: wordpress, csv

```
$imgurl = $_FILES['file'];
$pid = $_POST['pid'];

//print_r($imgurl);
if (!empty($imgurl)) {
    $uploadme = wp_upload_dir();
    if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }

    $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);
    $movefile  = wp_handle_upload($imgurl, $upload_overrides);

 print_r($movefile);
```

Hi, Above is the code i am trying to upload an csv file into the database in wordpress. everything is good as far as image is concerned but when i am trying to upload the .csv file then i am receiving an error.

```
[error] => Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://freewptp.com/fix-wordpress-issue-sorry-this-file-type-is-not-permitted-for-security-reasons/

Comment: Yes i tried this and added the code to my wp-config as well but it is only work if i am logged in as admin .. but my form is filled by anyone .

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php:

```
<?php
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
    $mimes['csv'] = 'application/octet-stream';

    return $mimes;
}

add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
?>
```

Comment: did this too but nothing happens actually this code will allow you to upload files from the backend ... only admin can able to upload the files from wp-admin. not users